# script checking html

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a http cgi command (http://cameraIP:port/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=getDevState&usr=user&pwd=password) which returns in browser

```
<CGI_Result>
    <result>0</result>
    <IOAlarm>0</IOAlarm>
    <motionDetectAlarm>1</motionDetectAlarm>
    <soundAlarm>0</soundAlarm>
    <record>0</record>
    <sdState>0</sdState>
    <sdFreeSpace>0k</sdFreeSpace>
    <sdTotalSpace>0k</sdTotalSpace>
    <ntpState>1</ntpState>
    <ddnsState>0</ddnsState>
    <url>http%3A%2F%2Fgg3460.myfoscam.org%3A22222</url>
    <upnpState>0</upnpState>
    <isWifiConnected>0</isWifiConnected>
    <wifiConnectedAP></wifiConnectedAP>
    <infraLedState>1</infraLedState>
</CGI_Result>
```

I want to create a script which will check if motionDetectAlarm equals to 2 and calls a restfull api put method. Is it possible?

I can call the resfull api with `curl -X PUT -d arg=val -d arg2=val2 localhost:8080`

How I can do the while loop? I want the loop running forever. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it not work?  Why do you want a while(true) loop rather than a cron job?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ran a cronjob every 100ms? How can I extract the motionDetectAlarm number? With sed?

Comment: Cron has a chronological resolution of one minute.  Do you really want to hit this every tenth of a second?

Comment: As to how to extract the data..  `sed -En '/motionDetectAlarm/s/([^0-9]+)//gp'` appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop "forever", pulling the web page and looking for the exact HTML code. `grep -q` will exit with "success" if the specific tag and value are present, which will allow the trailing `curl` to run:

```
while :
do
  wget or curl the CGIProxy script | grep -q '<motionDetectAlarm>2</motionDetectAlarm>' && 
    curl -X PUT -d arg=val -d arg2=val2 localhost:8080
done
```